# context destroyed, but ths session is still open

Tags: java, jsf, session-state

I'm new to jsf and I've read that a session can be destroyed

```
FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
HttpSession session = (HttpSession) fc.getExternalContext().getSession(false);      

fc.getExternalContext().getSessionMap().clear();

session.invalidate();
```

My problem ist, after doing that the session is still active, with the following bean :

```
com.sun.faces.renderkit.ServerSideStateHelper.LogicalViewMap
```

Do you have an idea?

Answer (score 2):

That's just a **new** session. To test it yourself, check the value of [`HttpSession#getId()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html#getId%28%29) during the request before and after invalidate. It should be different.

---

Unrelated to the concrete question, clearing the session map is unnecessary whenever you call `invalidate()`. The session map will be trashed anyway. Also note that `getSession(false)` can potentially return `null` and you'd like to add an extra check to avoid `NullPointerException`. Or just use `getSession(true)` instead.